# Java POJO xml annotation for attributes

Tags: java, annotations, marshalling, spring-batch

I am currently using a Spring Batch application to call an API and parse out the entire JSON response into an XML to be consumed by another application.  Currently we are using a rather large expand query with the API which sometimes times out on elements.  The required output format for the results is

```
<?xml version...?>
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP NAME="json.path.to.element.name">
            <PVAL>The value for the element</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP NAME="json.path.to.element2.name">
            <PVAL>The value for the element2</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        ...
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        ...
    </RECORD>
    ...
</RECORDS>
```

This was being created using a DOMSource and a Transformer. This unfortunately does not take advantage of the Spring Batch chunk processing. I am updating this to extend `StaxEventItemWriter` and passing a list of mapped objects.  My mapped entities are

```
@XmlElement
public class Record implements Serializable {

    private List<Prop> prop;
}

@XmlElement
public class Prop implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    private String pVal;
}
```

My Spring Batch XML config for my marshaller is

```
<bean id="xmlMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="aliases">
        <map>
            <entry key="RECORD" value="com...Record"/>
            <entry key="PROP" value="com...Prop" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem I am getting is my output format is not working. I am getting

```
<?xml version...?>
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
        <prop>
            <PROP>
                <name>json.path.to.element1.name"</name>
                <pVal>The value for the element1</pVal>
            </PROP>
                <name>json.path.to.element2.name"</name>
                <pVal>The value for the element2</pVal>
            </PROP>
            ...
        </prop>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <prop>
            ...
        </prop>
    </RECORD>
    ...
</RECORDS>
```

The two things that need to happen is 1) the `<prop>` entity needs to be removed as directly under the Record are all the `<PROP>` entities. and 2) the `<PROP>` needs to be `<PROP NAME...>`

I have tried messing with the annotations but can't seem to change the output. I am not even sure what the XSD would be for the desired structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of your question, the correct annotation for the name field should be as below if you want it to be an attribute.

```
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String name;
```

Following the [XStream annotation documents](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html) , the first part should be:

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="PROP")
private List<Prop> prop;
```